# Problem with parameters in CreateProcessAsUser

Tags: vb.net, winapi, windows-services, pinvoke, createprocessasuser

I've been assigned to build a windows service that is capable of launching a proccess into the current interactive user, using VB.NET 2005.

After some research, i've built the following code:

```
Dim hToken As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
Dim LastW32Error As Integer

If WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), hToken) Then
        Dim hTokenDup As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        If DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, Nothing, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, hTokenDup) Then
            Dim hEnv As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
            If CreateEnvironmentBlock(hEnv, hTokenDup, False) Then
                Dim strCommandLine As String = "c:\\windows\\system32\\NotePad.exe"
                Dim saProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = New SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                Dim saThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = New SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                Dim pi As New PROCESS_INFORMATION
                Dim si As New STARTUPINFO

                saProcessAttributes.nLength = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(saProcessAttributes))
                saThreadAttributes.nLength = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(saThreadAttributes))
                si.cb = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(si))

                If Not CreateProcessAsUser(hTokenDup, Nothing, strCommandLine, saProcessAttributes, saThreadAttributes, False, 0, hEnv, Nothing, si, pi) Then
                    LastW32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                    EvtLog.WriteEntry("CreateProcessAsUser: " + CStr(LastW32Error))
                End If
            Else
                LastW32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                EvtLog.WriteEntry("CreateEnvironmentBlock: " + CStr(LastW32Error))
            End If
            DestroyEnvironmentBlock(hEnv)
        Else
            LastW32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
            EvtLog.WriteEntry("DuplicateTokenEx: " + CStr(LastW32Error))
        End If
        CloseHandle(hTokenDup)
Else
    LastW32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    EvtLog.WriteEntry("WTSQueryUserToken: " + CStr(LastW32Error))
End If

CloseHandle(hToken)
```

But i'm getting the error 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) when calling CreateProcessAsUser. Somebody can point me what i'm doing wrong?

The code is implemented as a windows service that runs under LocalSystem account.

Comment: This is not possible anymore.  Google "session 0 isolation" to find out why.

Comment: @Hans I thought it was possible, and that this is the way to do it.

Comment: @Hans, it is still possible: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx -- The problem in my case is just CreateProcessAsUser the call.

Comment: Could you try passing nil for the two security attribute parameters. It would be nice to try and work out which parameter windows regards as invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- WTSQueryUserToken can only be called under LocalSystem
- WTSQueryUserToken returns a PrimaryToken. No need to duplicate it.
- This token already has the right sessionID and environment (it is derived from the currently logged on user), so there's no need to create an environmentblock

Comment: According to the documentation, the default environment block is not derived from the token but is copied from the calling process.